# Joining the table conditionally in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to join the two table based on the condition of the parameter that has been passed to the below sample query. If it is possible, thank you.

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(10)

SELECT A, B
FROM Table1 tb1 
JOIN Table2 tb2 ON tb1.A = tb2.A
INNER JOIN Table2 tb3 ON tb1.A = tb3.A
```

Now I want the above query to be like the one below. I know it is not correct but it is the sample of the output that I am looking for. If any idea will be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(10)

SELECT A, B
FROM Table1 tb1 
IF (@param = 'U')
  JOIN Table2 tb2 ON tb1.A
ELSE 
  INNER JOIN Table2 tb3 ON tb1.A = tb3.A
END
```

Comment: Do you mean that if `@param` is not `'U'`, then you want a simple select from Table1 with no join at all?

Comment: Do you intend to join do the same table either way? You have Table2 twice, did you mean there should be a Table3?

Comment: yes @DaveCosta You are correct!

Answer (score 3):

You can express this as a single join using `left join` and `coalesce()` in the `select`:

```
select A, coalesce(tb2.B, tb3.B) as B
From Table1 tb1 join
     Table2 tb2 
     on tb1.A = tb2.A and @param = 'U' join
     Table3 tb3 
     on tb1.A = tb3.A and @param <> 'U' and tb2.A is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your situation, and the execution plan.  Sometimes isolating the special case into a CTE and joining that into your main query is a good option.

```
WITH YourConditionalData AS (
    SELECT A, B
      FROM T2
        WHERE @param = 'U'
    UNION
      SELECT A,B
      FROM T3
        WHERE @param != 'U'
)
SELECT
   FROM T1 
   INNER JOIN YourConditionalData T ON T1.ID = T.ID
```

OR

```
WITH YourConditionalData AS (
    SELECT A, B
      FROM T1
        INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
        WHERE @param = 'U'
    UNION
      SELECT A,B
      FROM T1
        INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
        WHERE @param != 'U'
)
SELECT
   FROM YourConditionalData ....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @param varchar(10) = 'U' 
IF @param = 'U'

  SELECT *
  FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID

ELSE

  SELECT *
  FROM T1
    INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.ID = T3.ID
```

Thanks,